# How to call a function defined in same function on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

How to call a function defined in same function on click of hyperlink

```
Function A()
{
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');  
    aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");   
    aTag.innerHTML = "link text"; 
    mydiv.innerHTML=""; 
    mydiv.innerHTML=aTag; 

    Function B()
    {
        // do stuff ---           
    }    
}
```

On click of hyperlink aTag i need to call functionB. Please suggest.

Comment: You are calling the function B() or defining there ? Function within another function (nested function) may not supported by Java script.

Comment: @JDeveloper You can't say that! it totally works : [Nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function)

Comment: Sorry i was not clear. That's why i have used May not.

Answer (score 2):

```
aTag.onclick = function() {
  //...

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
aTag.onclick = function() {

    B();

}
```

or even shorter:

```
aTag.onclick = B;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call `function B` try this:

```
aTag.onclick = function() {
  var a = new A();
  a.B();
}
```