# How to add multiple callbacks to a javascript method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have created a simple javascript class using the 'function' technique.
In the class I have a websocket listener which triggers a function when a certain message is received.
I could easily add an external callback to it, as follows

```
function MyClass() {
    self = this; // to access main object from methods

    // websocket definition

    function websocketMessageInterpreter(message){
       if(message == "Hello!")  onHelloMessageBase();
     }

    function onHelloMessageBase(param){

    // call user defined callback
    self.userDefinedCallback(param);
    }
    this.userDefinedCallback= function(param){}; //default empty callback
}
```

Externally I use this as

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.userDefinedCallback = function(){alert("Someone said hello!");};
```

Is there a model where I could do something like this?

```
myObject.userDefinedCallback += function1;
myObject.userDefinedCallback += function2;
```

and maybe later

```
myObject.userDefinedCallback -= function1;
```

Comment: you could write [nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function) into the callback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to have an array of callbacks, and methods like `addCallback(callback)` and `removeCallback(callback)` to let users of the API add and remove callbacks.

`addCallback` is basically:

```
function addCallback(callback) {
    if (this.callbacks.indexOf(callback) < 0) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
    }
}
```

`removeCallback` is basically:

```
function removeCallback(callback) {
    var index;
    if ((index = this.callbacks.indexOf(callback)) >= 0) {
        this.callbacks.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

If you need to support really old browsers like IE6 which may not have `Array#indexOf`, since you're using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead.

Comment: Is `toString()` applied to the functions or how do you actually compare two functions, if they are the same?

Comment: @Amberlamps: It's a simply identity comparison, like for any other object.

Comment: @FelixKling: Okay, and that identity comparison also works for anonymous functions?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Yep... anonymous functions are just objects as well. It's totally independent from whether a function has a name or not.

Comment: Very interesting solution. I'm testing it and get back for the deserved acceptance