# How to Add Methods to a Function?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, methods

There are many ways to call functions in JavaScript, but this just isn't working for me. Could someone please tell me exactly what I'm doing wrong?

I tried prototyping (e.g. `gameObject.prototype = {};`), but that didn't work for some reason. Now I'm just trying to assign the methods directly within the function, and that isn't even working.

What's wrong with this picture?

```
function gameObject() {
    this.o = {};

    this.setimage = function(i) {
        this.o.img = i;
    };

    this.setDimensions = function(w, h) {
        this.o.width = w;
        this.o.height = h;
    };

    this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
        this.o.x=x;
        this.o.y=y;
    };

    this.create = function() {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.className = "object " + this.o.cname;
        el.style.width = width * this.o.w;
        el.style.height = height * this.o.h;
        el.style.position = "absolute";
        el.style.top = height * this.o.y;
        el.style.left = width * this.o.x;
        map.appendChild(el);
    };

    this.setClass = function(c) {
        this.o.cname = c;
    };

    return this.o;
}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
var d = new gameObject();
d.setClass("class");
d.setDimensions(0.8, 0.15);
```

I'm still fairly new to object oriented programming, so I don't even know if my vocabulary is correct. What is it that I'm trying to do and what's the proper way to do it exactly?

Comment: Why are you returning `this.o` from the constructor? I would just drop that, and your code should work.

Comment: Btw, how many game objects are you expecting to use?

Comment: It's a variable amount, considering I want to allow users to create their own in-game objects.

Answer (score 5):

You should not return anything from this constructor.

Remove this:

```
return this.o;
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSv6K/). 
If you return a value from a constructor, the object created will of the type of the returned value.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSv6K/2/).
If you see this demo, `d.a` returns `4` means `new gameObject` returned the `this.o` value instead of `this` which is the `gameObject()`.

If you want to use `prototype`:

```
function gameObject() {
    this.o = {};
}

gameObject.prototype = {
    setimage:function(i) {
        this.o.img = i;
    },
    setDimensions:function(w, h) {
        this.o.width = w;
        this.o.height = h;
    },
    setPosition:function(x, y) {
        this.o.x = x;
        this.o.y = y;
    },
    create:function() {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.className = "object " + this.o.cname;
        el.style.width = width * this.o.w;
        el.style.height = height * this.o.h;
        el.style.position = "absolute";
        el.style.top = height * this.o.y;
        el.style.left = width * this.o.x;
        map.appendChild(el);
    },
    setClass:function(c) {
        this.o.cname = c;
    }
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSv6K/1/).

Comment: That should not be such a generic statement; *in this case* nothing should be returned from the constructor :)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, the best way to create instance methods is using a prototype.  This code should work:

```
function gameObject(){
    this.o={};
};
gameObject.prototype = {
    setimage: function(i){
        this.o.img=i;
    },
    setDimensions: function(w,h){
        this.o.width=w;
        this.o.height=h;
    },
    setPosition: function(x,y){
        this.o.x=x;
        this.o.y=y;
    },
    create: function(){
        var el=document.createElement("div");
        el.className="object "+this.o.cname;
        el.style.width=width*this.o.w;
        e.style.height=height*this.o.h;
        el.style.position="absolute";
        el.style.top=height*this.o.y;
        el.style.left=width*this.o.x;
        map.appendChild(el);
    },
    setClass: function(c){
        this.o.cname=c;
    }
};
```

The issue with how you were doing it before was returning something - you don't need to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of using function methods within functions. I find this pattern easier to read and understand vs using classes or prototypes.

```
function Foo() {

  // Using this. makes the barf function accessible from Foo instances.
  // can also be written as: function this.barf (item) = {
  this.barf = (item) => { 
    console.log(`ate a ${item} and barfed!`);
  };

  // the eat function is internal to Food only (not using this.)
  let eat = (food) => {
    console.log(`ate: ${food}`);
  };

  // We can access eat within the function, but not outside.
  eat("apple"); 

  // We can also execute arbitrary code within the function (unlike using just an object to keep track of functions).
  console.log("too much foo'd"); 
}

let fooTest = new Foo();
fooTest.barf("pear");
```

Read more https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295712/1931185