# Is it possible to use function in MongoDB $where clause?

Tags: mongodb

I need to find out that if it is possible to use function in $where clause string like this:

```
db.myCollection.find( "this.name == 'xyz' || function() {return 1>0;} || this.name == 'abc'" );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but put all your checks in a single function that's the value of the `$where`:

```js
db.myCollection.find({$where: function() {
    return this.name == 'xyz' || 1>0 || this.name == 'abc';
}});
```

Comment: Yes, I know right approach but I just need to know that if simple conditions and more complex functions can be combined in a string for $where clause.

Comment: @Akdeniz Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just try what you're looking to do and see if it works?  I don't expect it will.

Comment: Actually I tried that and expected to get all myCollection data to return but on the contrary it returned nothing. At this point I don't know which one is the case: - it is possible to use function in string but im using improperly or - such usage is not possible and somehow function breaks the overall condition. btw thx for your time..

Comment: @Akdeniz theoretically it should work so long as it all runs within a evable statement like that but there could be some complication to its usage, I have never tried it.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use nested functions within functions in JS but there are some considerations as this question will tell you: [JavaScript Nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function)

However, as @JohnnyHK said, this isn't really a good way of doing a `$where`, if there is at all.