# Access function inside function inside object

Tags: javascript

I know that sounds weird, but bear with me.

I have an object like this:

```
Functions = {
    function1: function() {
        function2: function() {
            alert('bam');
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fire `function2`? I tried `Functions.function1.function2`and `Functions.function1().function2()` but none works. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How about Functions.function1()()?

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript syntax.  `Functions` is an object, so you can do `function1:`.  Inside that function, you cannot do `function2:`.

Comment: youll need to change the function two to be return now that I have put it in jsbin.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, actually, it should be valid in that it's the `function2:` label of an anonymous function.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Right, but the function definition is interpreted as function declaration and throwing an error.

Comment: @FelixKling, you're right, my bad. I just double checked myself after leaving the comment and it's missing the name.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Still, you are right, `function2:` itself is valid.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think [my answer to another question is relevant, if not quite a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7295712/497418).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two reworkings:

**Keeping the function2 label**

```
Functions = {
    function1: function() {
        function2: 
          (function() {
            alert('bam');
          })();      
    }
};

Functions.function1(); // You still can't access the label function2 however
```

**Removing the function2 label (switch for a return**

```
Functions = {
    function1: function() {
        return function() {
            alert('bam');
        };
    }
};

Functions.function1()();
```

Bottom line is that the code doesn't work as it stand because you cannot treat a label as if it was a property of a function.

The closest you could get (as far as I can tell) to calling function2 off of function1 is (without a return statement):

```
Functions = {
    function1: function() {
    }
};

Functions.function1.function2 = function() {
  alert("bam");
};

Functions.function1.function2();
```

Comment: Going with a `Removing the function2 label (switch for a return` example, how I can pass arguments to `function1`? `Functions.function1(param)()` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean like pass 'bam' to function1 and have it alert from inside the deeper nested function?

Comment: Something like `function1: function(elzar){ return function() { alert(elzar); }; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var test_func = {
        test1:function(){
           console.log("test1")
           return {
               test2:function(){
                  console.log("test2")
               }
           }
        }
    }
      test_func.test1().test2()
```