# Can someone explain these function definitions and hoisting?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Can someone please explain to me what is happening in following three examples?
My thoughts are for the first example, `bar` is not executed (it's just a function declaration) so when `foo` is executed, the output is `undefined`? For the second example, `bar` is executed so that value 3 is returned. For the third example I don't have a clue why it produces 8.

```
// 1)
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        return 3;
    }
}
foo(); // undefined

// 2) 
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
}
foo(); // 3

// 3)
function foo(){ 
    function bar(){
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
    function bar() { 
         return 8;
    }
 }
 foo(); // 8
```

Comment: `bar()` is declared twice in the third example. Since the second one is declared last, it returns 8.

Comment: 1) In 1st case, if you call foo(), foo() is executed and bar() is available now. But inorder to execute the bar you need to call it explicitly. 2) in second case, You are calling foo(), and in foo() bar is available, and you are calling bar() by writing return bar(); 3) In third case, see the explanation in second case. For extra info see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function

Comment: how to call bar explicitly?

Comment: @DaeYoung `return bar();`

Comment: @DaeYoung I mean, in first case, when you call foo(), bar() is available, but you are not calling the bar() function though it is availabale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct about examples 1 and 2, so I'll just address example 3.

While it looks like you're calling `bar()` before you redefine it, `function` declarations are treated specially. The functions are all defined when the containing scope is first entered, they're not executed in order. If you have multiple declarations for the same function, the last one is the effective one. So there's no difference between:

```
function bar() {
    // version 1
}
return bar();
function bar() {
    // version 2
}
```

and:

```
function bar() {
    // version 2
}
return bar();
```

This is the way that a function declaration differs from assigning a function expression to a variable. Had you instead written:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = function() {
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
    var bar = function() {
        return 8;
    }
}
foo();
```

then it would have returned `3`.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer because it mentions the var x = function syntax and when function declarations are executed.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer you're looking for is **hoisting**.

In your third example, what is really executed by the Javascript interpreter is:

```
var foo = function() { 
  var bar = function() {
    return 3;
  }
  var bar = function() { 
    return 8;
  }
  return bar();
}

foo(); // 8
```

The `function` declarations are processed first, on the scope of the function from which they have been called. I highly recommend you find more lecture about what hoisting is in Javascript, for instance you can start with this:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions on the first two examples are correct.

The last example returns `8` because `bar` is being redefined before `foo` is called. Here's a basic timeline of events:

1. `foo` is defined

   - `bar` is defined as a function that returns `3`
   - `bar` is redefined as a function that returns `8`
2. `foo` is invoked

   - the `return` statement is hit and the redefined `bar` function is executed, returning `8`

Answer (score 0):

In your third example, `bar()` is declared twice. The declaration that returns 8 is declared last, so it redefines `bar()` and is the declaration that is executed.

```
function foo(){ 
    function bar(){ // first declaration of bar()
        return 3;
    }

    return bar(); // this executes the code in bar() as it was most recently redefined

    function bar() { // second and last declaration of bar(); this redefines the
                     // first declaration
         return 8;
    }
 }
 foo(); // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function with the same name and scope is declared twice, it will ignore the first and execute the second function. That is what is occurring is #3.

Comment: so  return bar() is called after function bar(){ return 8; } declaration?

Comment: @DaeYoung Youe `return bar()` statement is what calls the method declared as `function bar(){ return 8; }`

Comment: When javascript is executed, hoisting will occur for the `var bar = function()`. This means it will be brought to the top of the scope since it is a variable declaration, and then functions which use/manipulate that data will be run (in this case, the `return` statement). Google javascript hoisting for more on that topic

Answer (score 0):

When the following is executed both function declarations are hoisted to the top of the `IIFE` scope - the second declaration overriding the first.

```
(function IIFE(){ 
    function bar(){
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
    function bar() { 
         return 8;
    }
})()

(function IIFE(){ 
    function bar(){
        return 3;
    }
    function bar() { 
         return 8;
    }
    return bar();
})()

(function IIFE(){ 
    function bar() { 
         return 8;
    }
    return bar();
})()
```