# How can i access innerFunction() in javascript from out side

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myName = {
        name : 'Rakesh',
        yearOfBirth : '1981',
        calculateAge : function(){
            console.log(this);
            console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);

            function innerFunction(){
                console.log("Hello World");
            }
            innerFunction();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `myName.calculateAge()` will call the `calculateAge` method and `innerFunction();` at the end of it will call `innerFunction`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one would be -

```js
var myName = {
  name: 'Rakesh',
  yearOfBirth: '1981',
  calculateAge: function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);
    function innerFunction() {
      console.log("Hello World");
    };
    return innerFunction;
  }
}

myName.calculateAge()();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope. So, normally you can't access innerFunction() in javascript from out side.

Unless you attach that function to an object outside.

```
var dummy = {};

var myName = {
            name : 'Rakesh',
            yearOfBirth : '1981',
            calculateAge : function(){
                console.log(this);
                console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);

                function innerFunction(){
                    console.log("Hello World");
                };

                innerFunction();

                dummy.innerFunction = innerFunction;

            }

        }

// Then you can do
myName.calculateAge(); // After you run this line, you will have dummy.innerFunction available
dummy.innerFunction();
```

That is a very dumb way to do it.