# Function in not define on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this code to resize ALL divs when one div is greater than other `divs`. The code executes on load then I want my nested function to work when window resizes. I am getting an error that `resizeAgain()` is not defined.

Updated: 
Forgot callback: `sameSize('.content', '.col1', '.col2');`

```
    <body onresize="resizeAgain()">
         function sameSize(e, selector1, selector2) {

        var slave = $(selector1).height();
        var master = $(selector2).height();
        var maxHeight = Math.max(slave, master);

        $(e).height(maxHeight);

        function resizeAgain() {
            $(e).css('height','');
            $(e).height(maxHeight);
        }
        sameSize('.content', '.col1', '.col2');
```

Comment: This code has a syntax error. My bet is that this is a scope error.

Comment: I forgot the callback function sameSize('.content', '.col1', '.col2');

Comment: I agree with Lee, but you should update your code first. The code provided is not correct. It misses brackets.

Comment: @NikxDa updated

Comment: Remove document.ready from within your resize function. It's used to init things on startup and shouldn't be used inside functions that aren't called on startup.

Comment: Not really. It's still not syntactically correct. Just post your complete code.

Comment: the function `resizeAgain` is only visible inside the scope of the `sameSize` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `resizeAgain` is only visible inside the scope of the `sameSize` function, that's why you have an error when you call it from the window scope.

You can define this function in the global scope :

```
<body onresize="resizeAgain('.content')">

function resizeAgain(e) {
  $(e).css('height','');
  $(e).height(maxHeight);
}

function sameSize(e, selector1, selector2) {
   var slave = $(selector1).height();
   var   master = $(selector2).height();
   var  maxHeight = Math.max(slave, master);
   $(e).height(maxHeight);
}

sameSize('.content', '.col1', '.col2');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `resizeAgain()` is defined in `sameSize(e, selector1, selector2)` and this changes its scope making it inaccessible outside `sameSize(..)`.

You can find more information at this other answer: [javascript-nested-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function)