# Extending Module in nodejs gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a simple animal.js module which extend in color.js module and output in app.js.

Animal.js:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.animalName = function() {
        console.log('Animal Name: Dog');
}
```

Color.js: Here I am extending the module animal.js and using it as a method of Color module i:e pAnimal();

```
var animal = require('./animal.js');

exports.animalColor = function() {
        console.log('Color is Black');

        function pAnimal() {
                var pAnimal = animal;
                pAnimal.animalName;
        }
}
```

App.js: Here I am trying to get value from color module as //Animal Name: Dog & //Color is Black

```
var localAnimal = require('./color.js');

localAnimal.animalColor();
localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal();
```

But when I run this in node server I get error like this:

```
    D:\node\module-extend>node app.js
    Color is Black
    D:\node\module-extend\app.js:4
    localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal();
                        ^

TypeError: localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\module-extend\app.js:4:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: how r u hitting the url..

Comment: running the app.js like this node app.js. But not listening any port/localhost. just using console

Comment: animal color is a function . try **localAnimal.animalColor().pAnimal()**

Comment: @dev9 he is not creating a server. He might be learning NodeJS or trying out few things

Comment: @manishkumar. Yes I am learning Nodejs. I tried localAnimal.animalColor().pAnimal() then output is only 'Color is Black'

Comment: @Sam i tried the answer i posted and its working. You can apply the same logic likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some answers about nested functions:
[JavaScript Nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function)

pAnimal is a function that can be called only inside animalColor scope.

To access it outside you have to do this:

```
exports.animalColor = function() {
        console.log('Color is Black');

        this.pAnimal = function() {
                var pAnimal = animal;
                pAnimal.animalName();
        }
}
```

Then:

```
var localAnimal = new require('./color.js');
localAnimal.pAnimal();
```

Comment: Tried your code and here's the output:
D:\node\module-extend>node app.js
Color is Black
D:\node\module-extend\app.js:4
localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal();
                        ^

TypeError: localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal is not a function

Comment: Call it as localAnimal.pAnimal();

Comment: outputs only 'Color is Black'

Comment: The () were missing in pAnimal.animalName(). Fixed.

Comment: This works!!. Could you please give some explanation why 'new' keyword is used and why pAnimal() is called directly on localAnimal variable ..for learning and future reference also. Thanks.

Comment: It’s the constructor pattern. AnimalColor works as a constructor and using “new” you’re creating a new instance. This is a great article to learn different ways to do it: https://team.goodeggs.com/export-this-interface-design-patterns-for-node-js-modules-b48a3b1f8f40

Answer (score 0):

Return the function in Color.js

```
exports.animalColor = function() {
        console.log('Color is Black');

       return  function pAnimal() {
                var pAnimal = animal;
                pAnimal.animalName();
        }
}
```

Call this way in app.js. just call below function it will print Color is Black
Animal Name: Dog

```
localAnimal.animalColor()();
```

Comment: I tried your code and this give the output as:
Color is Black
Color is Black

Comment: this way your trying to just get a output. But does not solve the purpose. My problem is with the error : localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal is not a function. Now in projects you have to call function inside a function by there namebut here i am calling it without name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the function to a property of the outer function to invoke it

**Like**

```js
function initValidation()
    {
        // irrelevant code here
        function validate(_block){
            console.log( "test", _block );
        }
    
        initValidation.validate = validate;
    }

    initValidation();
    initValidation.validate( "hello" );
```

So try

```
exports.animalColor = function() {
        console.log('Color is Black');
        animalColor.pAnimal=pAnimal;
        function pAnimal() {
                var pAnimal = animal;
                pAnimal.animalName;
        }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and here's the output :
 animalColor.pAnimal=pAnimal;
        ^

ReferenceError: animalColor is not defined

Comment: so pass the animal color to the function so that it traverses to the inner function.
atleast the **localAnimal.animalColor.pAnimal is not a function** error is gone